# Angular 2 - same component with different text

Tags: data-binding, angular, components

I would like to use same component many times, but with different text. How can I do that?

My code:
jumbotron.component.html:

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
   <h1 >{{jumbotronText}}</h1>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
            <navbar></navbar>
            <jumbotron ></jumbotron>
            <jumbotron ></jumbotron>
            <jumbotron ></jumbotron>
            `
            ,
directives: [NavbarComponent, JumbotronComponent]})
export class AppComponent { }
```

I tried do it like this:

```
        <jumbotron [jumbotronText]="My text to display"></jumbotron>
```

And this:

```
        <jumbotron jumbotronText="My text to display"></jumbotron>
```

But only got errors. I think that should be easy, but I cant find idea how to solve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will either need to use `@Input` or `ng-content`. By using the `{{  }}` syntax you are telling Angular to look for a variable named `jumbotronText` in `AppComponent`, but that doesn't exist.

#### Using `@Input()`

jumbotron.component.html

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>{{ jumbotronText }}</h1>
</div>
```

jumbotron.component.ts

```
@Component({
    // ...
}) export class JumbotronComponent {

    @Input() jumbotronText: string;

    // ...
}
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <navbar></navbar>
        <jumbotron [jumbotronText]="My text to display"></jumbotron>
        `
        ,
    directives: [NavbarComponent, JumbotronComponent]})
export class AppComponent { }
```

#### Using `ng-content`

jumbotron.component.html

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1><ng-content></ng-content></h1>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <navbar></navbar>
        <jumbotron>My text to display</jumbotron>
        `
        ,
    directives: [NavbarComponent, JumbotronComponent]})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you have to mark the jumbotronText with the Input() annotation in the Jumbotron component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'jumbotron',
  template: `
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
      <h1 >{{jumbotronText}}</h1>
    </div>`
})
export class JumbotronComponent {
  //here is important line
  @Input() jumbotronText:string = "";
  constructor() { }
}
```

Then, you can pass data in from the caller.  If it is static text you can do this:

```
template: `
  <navbar></navbar>
  <jumbotron jumbotronText="One" ></jumbotron>
  <jumbotron jumbotronText="Two" ></jumbotron>
  <jumbotron jumbotronText="Three" ></jumbotron>`
```

And if it is calculated text you do:

```
template: `
  <navbar></navbar>
  <jumbotron [jumbotronText]="variableFromCaller1" ></jumbotron>
  <jumbotron [jumbotronText]="variableFromCaller2" ></jumbotron>
  <jumbotron [jumbotronText]="variableFromCaller3" ></jumbotron>`
```

That is, if you have variables in the app component which store the strings (or methods, or are somehow otherwise calcualted) you use square brackets to indicate one-way binding.  Otherwise, if you have static text you just assign the Input() value the same as any other HTML tag property.

See this Plunker: https://embed.plnkr.co/ve31cnEDidcLeEF7dfVj/

Comment: Yeah i saw, that I didnt import Input. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Luke's answer. You must import the `Input` annotation from

```
@angular/core
```

When using the `@Input()` annotation on a property. You can add a string as a parameter to reference the property with an alias. 
Example: 
 `@Input("customTitle")`
  `Private title:string;`

You can later use 
`<my-directive [customTitle]="Custom" > </my-directive>`